# Akamai Integration

Tags: web-services, http, akamai

I want to use Akamai to store files. I want to know whether Akamai provides any API (e.g. web services) for us to upload, download, list files? Appreciate if anyone could provide some documents for a newbie.

Another question is, if I upload video files to Akamai, does it provide video streaming capability?

Comment: Does anyone have any comments?

Comment: If pricing is an issue - then I would go with Rackspace Cloud Files - much cheaper as they wholesale sell Akamai backed CDN - the Rackspace Cloud Files CDN is actually an Akamai solution - 75,000+ servers etc.. whole works, half the price. If you're a big boy company @George2 then go with Jiminy below..

Comment: Hi @George2, Were you able to find a solution to your problem. I am also looking for Akamai APIs using which I can upload/download/list files/get file, but not able to find anything useful. More specifically, I am looking for some jar or REST APIs using which I can do all the CRUD operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Akamai provide an API to allow your customers to download files.

From their web site it is called "Client-side Downloads"

> Client-side Downloads offers the ability to offload a significant
>   portion of edge delivery onto a managed and secure network of clients
>   - using client-to-client delivery - to provide a lower cost download
>   solution that respects the clients. **Good uses may include software
>   downloads, patches, and updates,** background software and drivers, and
>   downloadable video and games used by about a thousand or more people.

http://client.akamai.com/misc/demos

Here is further detail on how to interact with their API

http://client.akamai.com/misc/demos/csd-index.html

I was at their presentation the other day and they spoke about a Video Stream product coming out mid to late 2012.

I ran into another company that did video hosting and streaming called [Movideo](http://www.movideo.com/)